# ReactNative - button not showing up

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having trouble displaying my custom  component in ReactNative on Android simulator. Specifically, the  appears as a flat line (height is close to 0 - see the blue line immediately below "Authentication"), when it should have some height. How do I make the button have height? See below. Thanks!

[image]

Here's my code:

App.js (the parts that are relevant towards displaying the button)

```
renderContent() {
        return (
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        );
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header headerText="Authentication"/>
            {this.renderContent()} //button is rendered here.
        </View>
    );
}
```

Custom-defined button:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#007aff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#007aff',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }
};

export { Button };
```

Answer (score 3):

You should specify your custom button height.

```
    <View>
        <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication"/>
        </View>
        <View style={{height:50}}>
        {this.renderContent()} //button is rendered here.
        </View>
    </View>
```

Or you can use ScrollView instead.

```
    <View>
        <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication"/>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
        {this.renderContent()} //button is rendered here.
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

Comment: I had same problem. Forgot my View tag and was able to solve my issue by giving the View a height.